# Tensorflow convert array of tensors into single tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow

I'm building a LSTM RNN with Tensorflow that performs pixel-wise classification (or, maybe a better way to put it is, pixel-wise prediction?)

Bear with me as I explain the title.

The network looks like the following drawing...

[image]

The idea goes like this... an input image of size (200,200) is the input into a LSTM RNN of size (200,200,200). Each sequence output from the LSTM tensor vector (the pink boxes in the LSTM RNN) is fed into a MLP, and then the MLP makes a single output prediction -- ergo *pixel-wise prediction* (you can see how one input pixel generates one output "pixel"

The code looks like this (not all of the code, just parts that are needed):

```
...
n_input_x = 200
n_input_y = 200

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])

def RNN(x):
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input_x])
    x = tf.split(0, n_steps, x)

    lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    output_matrix = []
    for i in xrange(200):
        temp_vector = []
        for j in xrange(200):
            lstm_vector = outputs[j]
            pixel_pred = multilayer_perceptron(lstm_vector, mlp_weights, mlp_biases)
            temp_vector.append(pixel_pred)
        output_matrix.append(temp_vector)
        print i

    return output_matrix

temp = RNN(x)
pred = tf.placeholder(temp, [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)
...
```

I have confirmed that the output of `RNN` -- that is, what is stored in `temp` is a 200x200 array of `<tf.Tensor 'Softmax_39999:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>`

As you can see, I place `temp` in a `tf.placeholder` of the same shape (`None` for the batch size ... or do I need this?)... and the program just exits as if it completed running. Ideally what I want to see when I debug and print `pred` is something like `<tf.Tensor shape=(200,200)>`

When I debug, the first time I execute `pred = tf.placeholder(temp, [None, n_input_x, n_input_y])` I get `TypeError: TypeErro...32>]].",)` and then it `returns` and I try again, and it says `Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'" in <function _remove at 0x7f1ab77c26e0> ignored`

**EDIT** I also now realize that I need to place the lines

```
lstm_cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
outputs, states = rnn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Inside the first loop so that new 2D LSTM RNN are generated, however I'm getting an error about variable reusing `ValueError: Variable RNN/BasicLSTMCell/Linear/Matrix does not exist, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?`

So in other words, is it isn't auto incrementing the RNN tensor name?

Answer (score 0):

A more convenient way to report shapes is with tf.shape(). In your case:

```
size1 = tf.shape(temp)
sess = tf.Session()
size1_fetched = sess.run(size1, feed_dict = your_feed_dict)
```

That way, the size1_fetched is something like you would get from NumPy. Moreover, also your sizes for that particular feed_dict are given. For example, your [None, 200, 200] Tensor would be [64, 200, 200]

Another question: why do you have the placeholder in between your flow-graph? Will you later on feed pre-defined images feature-maps?

Comment: what I do `tf.shape(temp)` it returns a tensor... `<tf.Tensor 'Shape_1:0' shape=(4,) dtype=int32>` why is it `(4,)` and why is it an int32? the array itself if of shape `(200,200)` from your code, you just feed the model straight into a session without any sort of loss or optimizer function. I don't want to do that